# T-SQL average function - count 52 rows of data

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, average

I need help writing select statement that will do an average of the most recent 52 rows of data.

If there is less then 52 rows it will only do the avg of how many rows there are.

I know the avg function in SQL will skip the null...but i got this far.

```
SELECT AVG(E.Interest)
from InterestRates E
Where Interest in (select COUNT(Interest) <=52 from InterestRates)
```

i wanted for each row of data to go back and calculate the avg 52 rows
thanks

Comment: Please define what you mean by *the most recent 52 rows*.

Comment: the last 52 records entered into table

Comment: And how do you know what the last 52 records are?  Do you have an identity column, or some sort of time stamp?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT AVG(Interest) AS AvgInterest
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 52 E.Interest
    FROM InterestRates E
    ORDER BY DateEntered DESC
) Top52Interests
```

**EDIT**

Based on comments you can order by the identity instead:

```
SELECT AVG(Interest) AS AvgInterest
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 52 E.Interest
    FROM InterestRates E
    ORDER BY YourIdentityField DESC
) Top52Interests
```

The nice thing is this query will work in SQL 2000 as well.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT
AVG(E.Interest) 
FROM
InterestRates E 
WHERE
ROWNUMBER() <= 52
ORDER BY whatever DESC;